# Pagination using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, accordion

Trying to implement pagination for jQuery accordion using javascript. I found this [link](http://pastebin.com/wZ8ztedJ) for a javascript class to implement accordion pagination. However, it's not behaving  as expected. I played with it for a while but with no result.  Can someone please help me figure where the fault is? I'd appreciated so much. Here I created [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mdu7faf/) for it.

Javascript code

```
     var paginatorHandle = null;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#dalist").accordion({
    autoHeight: false
});

paginatorHandle = jQuery("#dalist").paginateAccordion({
    "currentPage": 0,
        "itemsPerPage": 3,
        "paginatorControl": jQuery("#accordionPaginator")
});

// initial paginate call
paginatorHandle.paginate();

jQuery("#accordionPaginator .nextPage").click(function () {
    paginatorHandle.nextPage();
});

jQuery("#accordionPaginator .previousPage").click(function () {
    paginatorHandle.previousPage();
});

jQuery("#accordionPaginator .goToPage").change(function () {
    var pageIndex = parseInt($(this).val(), radix);
    paginatorHandle.goToPage(pageIndex);
   });
});


//this is the main class

function AccordionPaginator(element, currentPage, itemsPerPage, paginatorControl) {
this.element = element;
this.currentPage = currentPage;
this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
this.paginatorControl = paginatorControl;

// does the actual pagination (shows/hides items)
this.paginate = function () {
    var index = this.currentPage * this.itemsPerPage;

    element.accordion("activate", index);
    element.children().hide();

    if (index < 0) {
        this.element.children("div:first").show();
        this.element.children("h3:first").show();
    } else {

        this.element.children("div:eq(" + index + ")")
            .show();

        this.element.children("h3:eq(" + index + "),h3:gt(" + index + ")")
            .filter(":lt(" + this.itemsPerPage + ")")
            .show();
    }

    this.refreshControl();
};

// increments the currentPage var (if possible) and calls paginate
this.nextPage = function () {
    if (this.currentPage + 1 >= this.getMaxPageIndex()) {
        return;
    }

     this.currentPage++;
    this.paginate();
};

// decrements the currentPage var (if possible) and calls paginate
this.previousPage = function () {
    if (this.currentPage - 1 < 0) {
        return;
    }

    this.currentPage--;
    this.paginate();
};

// sets currentPage var (if possible) and calls paginate
this.goToPage = function (pageIndex) {
    if ((pageIndex < 0) || (pageIndex >= this.getMaxPageIndex())) {
        return;
    }

    this.currentPage = pageIndex;
    this.paginate();
    };

// returns the maximum of pages possible with the current number of items
this.getMaxPageIndex = function () {
    var items = this.element.children("h3");
    var fullPages = items.length / this.itemsPerPage;
    var restPage = items.length % (this.itemsPerPage > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    return fullPages + restPage;
};

// fills up the paginator control
this.refreshControl = function () {
    if (this.paginatorControl === null) {
        return;
    }

    var pageList = this.paginatorControl.children(".goToPage");
    pageList.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.getMaxPageIndex(); i++) {
        pageList.append("<option value=\"" + i + "\">" + (i + 1) + "</option>");
    }
    pageList.val(this.currentPage);
};
}

jQuery.fn.extend({
paginateAccordion: function (options) {
    var currentPage = options.currentPage ?parseInt(options.currentPage, radix) : 0;
    var itemsPerPage = options.itemsPerPage ? parseInt(options.itemsPerPage, radix) : 5;
    var paginatorControl = options.paginatorControl;

    return new AccordionPaginator(this, currentPage, itemsPerPage, paginatorControl);
    }
});
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem it is working well !

Comment: How is it working well? do you see the drop down box? It's not showing pages numbers if you click it.. It should display 3 items per page but it isn't.

Comment: That's a lot of code for a lack of specific questions.

Comment: My question is why isn't it paging the accordion? I can't locate where the fault is

Comment: jQuery("#dalist").paginateAccordion what is that ? please provide your original source.

Comment: I have included the source in the question description, here it is again [link](http://pastebin.com/wZ8ztedJ)

Comment: it looks like `paginateAccordion` is undefined when it is called...I see that your are using `jQuery.fn.extend` to define it which works, but it's losing in a race condition

Comment: @almightyBoognish what do you mean by "its losing in a race condition"

Comment: @ProllyGeek could you point out those mistakes?

Comment: "its losing in a race condition" - the almightyBoognish means that you are trying to call paginateAccordion before it has been defined, i.e. there is a race to see if it can be defined before the call, and the definition is losing, hence the error showing up in the JavaScript console. Try doing the extend in the document ready before you make the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made couple of changes to your code in JSFiddle and the pagination worked.
Here is the link to the modified jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/moLwmyyr/

I removed

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

And used JSFiddle Frameworks and Extensions to include jQuery

I changed the jQuery UI include to

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I moved the

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    paginateAccordion: function (options) {
        var currentPage = options.currentPage ?parseInt(options.currentPage, 10) : 0;
        var itemsPerPage = options.itemsPerPage ? parseInt(options.itemsPerPage, 10) : 5;
        var paginatorControl = options.paginatorControl;

        return new AccordionPaginator(this, currentPage, itemsPerPage, paginatorControl);
    }
});
```

Above your document ready method.

And changed the following line.

element.accordion("activate", index);

**To**
element.accordion("option", "activate", index);

The pagination works.
I observed some glitch when you go to the next page and click on the section 5, it is not collapsing section 4.